# what is the triple dollar sign in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to debug someone's code, and came across this:

```
$$$.ajax({
    url: ajax_url + param,
    context: $("#formDialog"),
    success: function(data) {
        this.html(data);
        BindPopupFormEvents(this, title, reload);
    }
}, $$$.ajax.PARTAIL_UPDATE, $mainWrapper);​
```

We are using the jquery library, but I've never seen a triple dollar sign before and I have no clue what it is... any suggestions?

**EDIT**

I found this later on:

```
$$$.fn = $$$.prototype = {
    init: function(jQuery, test) {},
    CONST: CONST
};​
```

We are only using the jquery library, and we use a single dollar sign in most of the code.

can you explain in plain english what the triple dollar sign is accomplishing, please?

Comment: I really have no idea what the "later on" stuff is supposed to do :(

Comment: Regarding to your edit: Then it just stupid... unless `$$$` refers to a different jQuery version than `$`., You know what, after second thought, That's stupid as well... `:)`

Comment: I know it's more than two years... but I've seen your edit just now... See my updated answer. Sorry for the delay. `:)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's just an alias to the `jQuery` object, just like `$`. That's all...

In can be done by hand or with [`jQuery.noConflict()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Examples:

```
var $$$ = jQuery.noConflict();
var bla = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Now both `$$$` and `bla` are aliases to the `jQuery` object.

> Many JavaScript libraries use $ as a function or variable name, just as jQuery does. In jQuery's case, $ is just an alias for jQuery, so all functionality is available without using $. If we need to use another JavaScript library alongside jQuery, we can return control of $ back to the other library with a call to $.noConflict():

---

**Edit to reflect your edit:**

Though I see only small portion of the code but `$$$.fn = $$$.prototype` seems silly as `jQuery.fn` is an alias to `jQuery.prototype`...

From the source code:

```
jQuery.fn = jQuery.prototype
```

Answer (score 3):

`$$$` is just a[nother] JavaScript identifier.

The property `$$$` is *not* defined by jQuery, but presumably someone did something like this:

```
$$$ = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Perhaps to avoid overwriting a `$` from another library. Although I find it to be quite hideous and would opt to just bind `$` to `jQuery` in a closure:

```
;(function myStuff ($, evil$) {
   // do stuff with $ (jQuery) and "the other $"
})(jQuery, $) // <-- keep us real
```

Comment: but we use a single dollar sign all over, why in this one case would we use a triple one? we are only loading the jquery library

Comment: @estherh Perhaps code from Dr. Evils Awesome Library uses `$`. Or perhaps a developer thought more money (`$$$`) was better than less money (`$`). I would *not* recommend this approach, though :)

Comment: haha :-) i would have chose both yours and gdoron as the "correct" answer, but had to choose only one... thanks for the input though